# Angular XEditable Dialog

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I have an AngularJS application in which I use Xeditable in order to modify table values on the fly.
I am using a standard method of editing values without showing any buttons and using the blur attribute in order to submit all my changes rapidly and in-line.

```
<a href="#" buttons="no" blur="submit">{{ myValue }}</a>
```

Instead of the confirmation being seen as buttons such as on countless examples, they should be only shown in a dialog upon saving (onblur).

Due to user interaction issues, I would like to show a confirmation dialog when a field is changed and then clicked away from (or when the field exits its edit state). Basically something within the "***onbeforesave***=" attribute.

This is when the confirmation should pop up informing that user that the value was changed and asking if they want to save it or not.

I know how call a function on the ***onbeforesave*** event although since it lies within the controller I don't know how to invoke a confirmation dialog.

The basic Steps are as follows:

> 1. User Clicks on a table cell value
> 2. Cell becomes editable.
> 3. User changes the cell value.
> 4. User clicks away from the cell.
> 5. small confirmation dialog pops up (any user friendly or boostrappy way)
> 6. User confirms or cancels the edit which was made.
> 7. Rinse / Repeat.

Any help is appreciated.

See current [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17jnyqfL/8/)

***UPDATE:*** My latest attempts lead me to implement  angular-dailog-service which solved my initial problem above, but I am still unable to resolve the final part of my original question.

Upon clicking onto a cell, changing a value and clicking away, I receive a dialog window (confirmation) which when I hit *YES* will call my api and save the value - which works. Upon clicking *NO* however, my value remains changed in the table. This value now needs to be reverted to the previous value. Any help?

> - I now use a *onshow* attribute in order to save my current value of the cell being edited to the scope.
> - I use the *onbeforesave* attribute in order to launch my dialog and perform the Yes/No check.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" editable-text="myValue" buttons="no" blur="submit" onbeforesave="launchDialog($data)" onshow="onShow($data)" >{{ myValue || 'empty' }}</a>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.oldValue = "";

    $scope.onShow = function(data){
      $scope.oldValue = data;
      };

    $scope.launchDialog = function(data) {
      var dlg = null;
      dlg = dialogs.confirm('Value Changed','Do you want to save this change?');
      dlg.result.then(function(btn){

        //TODO: HIT API AND SAVE VALUE

      },function(btn){
        //RESET TO OLD VALUE
        return "";
      });

    };
```

The final piece of the puzzle if figuring out what needs to happen inside my *NO* click function (where the *RESET TO OLD VALUE* is).

Comment: [Here is some inspiration](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/645/)

Comment: Already seen this and played around with it. Thought about using a directive which is easy for button clicks, but it doesn't cover my requirement. i'm unsure how exactly to make it function the way i explained above. An actual explanation/idea or a short fiddle would be more appreciated. Thanks for your effort though :")

Comment: I am currently thinking of trying to use the angular-dialog-service by m-e-conroy (on github). Will try using this in order to get the functionality I need and will update with my findings. If anyone thinks of any easier method, please let me know in the mean time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to complete my task by adding xeditable and doing everything as follows, exactly as I wanted from the start.
The dialog is launched with the attribute *onbeforesave* : `onbeforesave="launchDialog(this.$editable.name, $data)"`

1. Add x-editable
2. Create a scope property in my controller to store my old value. This is done on the onShow event.
3. Add an e-ng-keypress (editable state keypress event)
4. Make relevant changes in the controller.

*PS: Worrying about how to fill the table data via json at a later stage may complicate things, and you will likely need to create variables for each entry but it is still doable for my purposes.*

**HTML:**

```
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in [1,2]">
                            <td>{{ item }}</td>
                            <td><a href="#" editable-text="avg.jan" e-name="jan" e-ng-keypress="enterpress($event, this.$editable.name)" buttons="no" blur="submit" onbeforesave="launchDialog(this.$editable.name, $data)" onshow="onShow($data)" >{{ avg.jan || 'empty' }}</a></td>
 <td><a href="#" editable-text="avg.jan" buttons="no" blur="submit">{{ avg.jan || 'empty' }}</a></td>
```

I added a comparative standard *td* above as well to show the new changes.

**Controller**

The controller will need a few things, somewhere to store and then assign the old variable (if a value is changed and then cancelled). It will also need the Enter keypress detection, saving and the dialogue code.

```
$scope.oldValue = "";

    $scope.onShow = function(data){
      $scope.oldValue = data;
      };


    $scope.saveData = function(key, data) {
      //TODO: SAVE DATA TO API
    }

    $scope.enterpress = function (e, data) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        $scope.saveData();
      }
    }

    $scope.launchDialog = function(key, data) {
      var dlg = null;

      if(data != $scope.oldValue) {

        //ON ENTER KEY PRESS SKIP THE DIALOG + SAVE

        dlg = dialogs.confirm('Value Changed', 'Do you want to save this change?');
        dlg.result.then(function (btn) {
          //SAVE VALUE
          $scope.saveData(key, data);

        }, function (btn) {
          //RESET OLD VALUE
          $scope.avg[key] = $scope.oldValue;

        });
      }
    };
```

Overall im glad I finally figured this out, pulled out a few hairs but it was fun in the end. Hope it serves to help someone with similar requirements: A way in which to extend xeditable functionality.